# Looking to use functional programming to solve repeated code

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I have some code that is repeated often with the same pattern, which I have included below as pseudocode.

I have a number of methods that have the same transaction code **(see A.)**, and then DB code which is always different for each method **(see B.)**. The code at **B** needs to be executed inside an anonymous class.

```
public static Foo doMyDatabaseStuff(ApplicationContext context, WebSite webSite) {

    //A. Do a bunch of boilerplate Transaction stuff

    TransactionUtils transactionUtils = getTransactionUtils(context);

    Foo foo = (Foo) transactionUtils.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
        public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus ts) {

            //B. Do a bunch of use case specific DB stuff

            FooDao fooDao = (FooDao) context.getBean("FooDao");
            Foo foo = fooDao.create(webSite);
            {
                foo.setName("Administratoren");
                foo.setSite(webSite);
                //call a bunch of other setters
                fooDao.update(foo);

                return foo;
            }
        }
    });
    return foo;
}
```

I feel like this is a perfect candidate for functional programming. I have a bunch of code I want to execute, but I want to wrap it in some other function (ie. use a higher order function).

My naive attempt at using the Function interface yielded this :

```
public Foo doMyDatabaseStuff(ApplicationContext context, WebSite webSite) {

    Function<ApplicationContext, Foo> func = new Function<ApplicationContext, Foo>() {

        public Foo apply(ApplicationContext context) {
            FooDao fooDao = (FooDao) context.getBean("FooDao");

            Foo foo = fooDao.create(webSite);
            {
                foo.setName("Administratoren");
                foo.setSite(webSite);
                //call a bunch of other setters
                fooDao.update(foo);

                return foo;
            }

        }
    };

    return DefaultContents.executeTransaciton(context, func);
}



public static Foo executeTransaciton(ApplicationContext applicationContext, Function f) {


    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = getTransactionTemplate(applicationContext);

    Foo retval = (Foo) transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
        public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus ts) {
            return f.apply(applicationContext);
        }
    });

    return retval;
}
```

I feel like this is going on the wrong track because

- The 'executeTransaciton' method is locked into using the 'Foo' object. It should, I guess, return **Object**.
- The Function generics are a bit weird. I want to pass in all my variables from the parameters in the doMyDatabaseStuff method (ie. the enclosing method scope), rather than passing in via the **apply(param)** method.
- It doesn't look like I am saving that much in boilerplate code, I still have to add this bulky 'function' anonymous class code to each method.

Am I on the right track here?... or completely off?

Comment: Why can't you just pass in a `TransactionCallback` as a method parameter? Does it really need to be "functional"?

Comment: you are probably right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all that is different is what you do in the `TransactionCallback`, simply pass in the `TransactionCallback` as a parameter to a method which does the "boilerplate Transaction stuff", and then executes the `TransactionUtils`:

```
private static Foo doMyDatabaseStuff(ApplicationContext context, WebSite webSite, TransactionCallback cb) {

    //A. Do a bunch of boilerplate Transaction stuff

    TransactionUtils transactionUtils = getTransactionUtils(context);

    return (Foo) transactionUtils.execute(cb);
}
```

and call this method from your existing method:

```
public static Foo doMyDatabaseStuff(ApplicationContext context, WebSite webSite) {
    return doMyDatabaseStuff(context, webSite, new TransactionCallback() {
        public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus ts) {

            //B. Do a bunch of use case specific DB stuff

            FooDao fooDao = (FooDao) context.getBean("FooDao");
            Foo foo = fooDao.create(webSite);
            {
                foo.setName("Administratoren");
                foo.setSite(webSite);
                //call a bunch of other setters
                fooDao.update(foo);

                return foo;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: yeah, i had a feeling that i was trying to solve a problem with the wrong tool

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your specific stuff is a `BiFunction<ApplicationContext, WebSite, T>`.

```
BiFunction<ApplicationContext,WebSite,Foo> yourExample = (context, webSite) -> {
        FooDao fooDao = (FooDao) context.getBean("FooDao");
        Foo foo = fooDao.create(webSite);
        foo.setName("Administratoren");
        foo.setSite(webSite);
        //call a bunch of other setters
        fooDao.update(foo);

        return foo;
};
```

Now, to put that in your transaction, you might do

```
public static <T> T doMyDatabaseStuff(BiFunction<ApplicationContext, WebSite, T> dbStuff) {
    TransactionUtils transactionUtils = getTransactionUtils(context);
    // Note that the cast is safe, the function returns a T
    T foo = (T) transactionUtils.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
        public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus ts) {
            return dbStuff.apply(context, webSite);
        }
    });
    return foo;
}
```